# Show Hide Div Dependent on Get ['status']

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-animate

Hopefully someone will know how to do this...
I would like the show/hide to work dependent on the the image/icon clicked.

For example if Request Icon is clicked, the colorbox popup will be displaying the Request and `Offered` divs. 
Whereas if the Accepted Icon is clicked, the colorbox popup will display Accepted and `Offered` Divs but hides the `Request` div.

Here's a few in the PHP:

```
      <div <?php if($_GET['status']=="Requested"){ echo "class=iconActive";}else {echo "class=iconInactive";}?>>
        <a href="/index.php/agent-appointment-request-list/?status=Requested">
        <img src="components/com_agent/images/requestedIcon_s1.png" id="requestedIcon" alt="" /></a>
        <div class="iconTitle">Requested</div>
        </div>
```

Here's the jquery for show/hide that I have:

```
 $(".slidingDivReq").show();
 $("#show_hideReq").show();

 $('#show_hideReq').click(function(){
     $(".slidingDivReq").slideToggle();
 });
```

Update: Here's the section for the content that'll be show/hidden. :

```
<div class="AppointmentTitleFirst">
    <img src="components/com_agent/images/req_appt_title_s1.png" class="ApptIcon"></img>
    <h1>Requested Appointment # <?php echo $this->appointment->id;?>         Status:<?php echo $this->appointment->status_name;?></h1>
    <img src="components/com_agent/images/dropdown_arrow_s1.png" class="ApptDropDownArrow1" id="show_hideReq"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="clearFloat"></div>
    <div id="requestedAppointmentContent" class="slidingDivReq">
 Content here....
 </div>
```

Pretty much, I'm not sure how to use the `GET['status']` and use it with the show/hide. So if the `GET['status'] == Requested`, then the `show_hideReq` will be `.show()`, but my other divs in the colorbox will use `.hide();` (unless it's a page that needs a few other divs to `.show()`)

Hopefully someone will know.

Comment: The classes and IDs mentioned in your jQuery don't match with any of the elements in the HTML you provided, so you've either provided a wrong or incomplete section of HTML or that's your reason that it doesn't work.

Comment: Also, may or may not be relevant based on the response to my other comment, but: You attach a class of `iconActive` to the `<div>` element if `$_GET['status']=="Requested"` so you could check for the presence of that class (using the `.hasClass()` jQuery function) if that `<div>` element is the element you want to show or hide.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not sure how to use the GET['status'] and use it with the
>   show/hide

You can use a *hidden* element as a variable, sothat you can test your `GET['status']` in jquery. Add this element in your php page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="StatusId" value="<?php echo GET['status']; ?>"/>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$('#div').click(function(){
   var statusId = $("#StatusId").val();
   If( statusId  === 0){
       //Do something
   }else{
       // Do something elese
   }
});
```

You *should* send the `status` value in the url that redirect to this php page, for example from js file it would look like:

```
 var url = "http://localhost/yourcurrentphpfile.php?Status=" + somevalue;
 window.location.href = url;
```

or the clicked `<a>` tag in your php page that redirect to this page should has the `href` property looks like `http://localhost/yourcurrentphpfile.php?Status=somevalue`.

`yourcurrentphpfile.php` is the php page that containst the hidden input.

Comment: Hi MGA, I was just trying your solution, and I'm not sure why but I don't believe it's retrieving the status correctly on my end. i noticed, that when I placed the "<input id="StatusId" value="<?php echo $_GET['status']; ?>"/>" to not be hidden, there was no value for the status, even though it clearly said "status=Requested" on the browser.

Comment: @Nina, you should add `type=hidden` to be hidden, then make sure you sent the status variable in the get request from the url that redirect to this page, see my edit

Comment: I'm sure in some way this should work, but when I attempted it, it just wouldn't work on my end. There must be something else interfering. :/

Comment: @Nina, How this doesn't work, Can you update the question with your recent code you are using, BTW you can use firebug to debug your javascirpt code and see if there is a problem in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use `$(element).css("dissplay","none");` to hide an element and `$(element).css("dissplay","inherit");` to show it.

Also in your PHP you better use `if (isset($_GET['status']) && !empty($_GET['status']))` to ensure you have a value. Also, you need to edit your ECHO instructions to:

```
echo 'class = "iconActive"';
```

and

```
echo 'class = "iconInactive"';
```

Following your code's logic,

```
$(function(){ //on page load
     $("div.classActive").load(function(){
         //Do whatever you want when the div is active such as show/hide elements
     })
     $("div.classInactive").load(function(){
         //Do whatever you want when the div is inactive such as show/hide elements
     })
})
```

Only of the 2 will be executed since when a page renders only one of them will exist.

Comment: [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: Or that, it's the same result!